# Firebase Mac development: Can I use firebase with cocoa app?

Tags: objective-c, database, cocoa, firebase

I am developing a mac app with objective-c. I need a database service that is easy to use. I'm considering firebase but I found it doesn't provide any documentation for desktop app. :(  I wonder whether I can use its ios documentation for mac app? Or is there any other similar database service that is easy to use support mac app?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By “document” did you mean documentation or something else? Edit Question to clarify.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks! I've added it.